Root partition is out of space in Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
While installing Ubuntu, I allocated 40GB to my root, and the space left was allowed for another partition mounted at home. My root is almost full and I'd like to resize it. Please how do I go about it?

Clean your root up. Free it from snap install is the best method.
